# Logical Difference between publishing add-on on chrome web store vs Google marketplace

Tags: marketplace, google-workspace

Trying to develop an add-on for G suite spreadsheet users. This add-on eventually needs to publish on G suite marketplace. Flow will be as follows -- > User will search add-on/app on G suite marketplace(https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace) and then install this app which will enable add-on across all of his spreadsheets.

My question are; 
1. What is the logical difference in publishing add-on on 'chrome web store' vs 'G suite marketplace'. Both the places looks very similar to me.

2. Can I publish my add-on/app on 'G suite marketplace' which will be 'public' to any general google users like I can do it for 'chrome web store'.